# passport local mongoose register doesn't execute callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, passport-local-mongoose

Now I'm using passport-local-mongoose, and User.register method so that a new user is stored in the database.

Successfully, a new user can be added, but I encountered a problem right after it; the callback function is not working. In the code below, console.log("This string is supposed to be displayed.") should be executed.

I would like to ask why it is not executed.

```
app.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
console.log("req body username is : " + req.body.username);
console.log("req body password is : " + req.body.password);

User.register({ username: req.body.username }, req.body.password), function (err, user) {
    console.log("This string is supposed to be displayed.");
    
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error in User registration", err);
    } else {
        passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function () {
            res.send("you are registered.")
            console.log("passport authenticate works.");
        })
    }
}
```

All users added can be seen in the database, so I'm really confused by this. No error message appears with the code above.

Comment: passport.use(User.createStrategy());

passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());

passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser()); are used

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. An unnecessary parenthesis was added.

```
User.register({ username: req.body.username }, req.body.password, function (err, user) {
```